# Using an AND statement in a CASE in t sql

Tags: t-sql, case

I am trying to make a case statement where one of the WHEN's contains an AND.

```
Declare @FROM DateTime = 'OCT 1 2015 12:00AM'
,case   when isnull(SS.VerificationFlag,0) = 1 then 1 
        when isnull(SS.ExperationDate1,@FROM) >= @FROM AND isnull(SS.ExperationDate2,@FROM) >= @FROM then 1
        else 0
 END
```

I am getting a 1 as output when ExperationDate1 passes and ExperationDate2 fails.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that your SS.VerificationFlag is 1 when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your case statement.  I tried it in a select clause and it works as expected.  I believe that you're getting a 1 because the first case is true.  That is:

```
 when isnull(SS.VerificationFlag,0) = 1 then 1
```

fires before you get to the more complicated clause with an AND statement.

Comment: I am embarrassed that this is the actual issue. I must be having a bad day. Thank you.

Comment: No worries.  Easy mistake to make if you're concentrating on the syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE SS;
go

create table SS (
  VerificationFlag tinyint,
  ExpirationDate1 datetime,
  ExpirationDate2 datetime
)

INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (0, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (0, '20140214', NULL)
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (0, NULL, '20160619')
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (0, '20140214', '20160619')
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, '20140214', NULL)
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, NULL, '20160619')
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, '20140214', '20160619')
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, '20160214', NULL)
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, NULL, '20140619')
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (1, '20160214', '20140619')
INSERT INTO SS(VerificationFlag, ExpirationDate1, ExpirationDate2) VALUES (0, '20160214', '20140619')

DECLARE @from DATETIME;
SET @from = '20151001';

SELECT
    SS.VerificationFlag,
    SS.ExpirationDate1,
    SS.ExpirationDate2,
    @from AS FromDate,
    CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(SS.VerificationFlag, 0) = 1 THEN 1 
    WHEN (ISNULL(SS.ExpirationDate1, @from) >= @from) AND (ISNULL(SS.ExpirationDate2, @from) >= @from) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS ResultingFlag
FROM SS
```

With results:

```
VerificationFlag ExpirationDate1         ExpirationDate2         FromDate                ResultingFlag
---------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------
0                NULL                    NULL                    2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
0                2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 NULL                    2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 0
0                NULL                    2016-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
0                2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 2016-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 0
1                NULL                    NULL                    2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 NULL                    2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                NULL                    2016-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 2016-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                NULL                    NULL                    2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                2016-02-14 00:00:00.000 NULL                    2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                NULL                    2014-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
1                2016-02-14 00:00:00.000 2014-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 1
0                2016-02-14 00:00:00.000 2014-06-19 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 0
```